# Python Ignore lines in file that start with

Tags: python

I am new to python. Within my python script I open a file for reading, and want to process certain lines. I want to ignore lines that start with either '*' or '#'. Here is my code:

```
line = DLF_P.readline()

while line:

if not line.startswith('*') or not line.startswith('#'):

    time = line.split()[0]
    print time
    time = datetime.strptime(time, FMT)

    if start < bdoyend:
        print time

line = DLF_P.readline()
```

I get the error that the first line (which contains an asterisk) does not match the format 'HH:MM:SS". I thought my code would ignore these types of lines.

> ValueError: time data '**' does not match format '%H:%M:%S'

Am I doing this wrong?

Comment: one of the lines in your input doesn't match the time format FMT. check which lines are different, and if you can provide an example of what the input looks like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line

```
if not line.startswith('*') or not line.startswith('#'):
```

should be

```
if not line.startswith('*') and not line.startswith('#'):
```

or

```
if not (line.startswith('*') or line.startswith('#')):
```

if you want to ignore both lines starting with `*` and those starting with `#`

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid, but I got it now. Thank you all for helping, it is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are checking if the line doesn't start with **EITHER** `*` or `#`, you need to do this:

```
if not line.startswith('*') and not line.startswith('#')
```

Comment: Ok, I got it. I feel stupid for missing that logic, but I really appreciate all for taking time to help.